# which utilities busybox does replace?

Tags: busybox

I know one can list what commands are enabled in busybox with the $busybox command, but I was curious as to which utilities/packages busybox actually can replace (say util-linux, pciutils, usbutils, coreutils, binutils, findutils, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Busybox was designed and implemented to be the only binary in a system. It implements hundreds of binaries.

You could potentially work out a definitive list of packages by 1) taking the full list of binaries that busybox implements from the website, then 2) mapping each to an installed package (such as using `dpkg -S $(which <bin>)` on Debian). Some might not be on your system, you'll need to figure those out separately.

Comment: I have checked busybox command list already, I just want to know what utilitiy packages it does or does not replace and any overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

According to the `busybox 1.31.1` `menuconfig` those are the utilities covered by `busybox`

you can always view this menu as the following:

- if you are building from the source `make menuconfig` in the busybox directory.
- if you are using buildroot `make busybox-menuconfig`
- if you are using Yocto project `bitbake -c menuconfig busybox`

[image]